# LinkedBlockQueue can't pass Watchable

Tags: java

I want to ask you something i'm doing like that ..

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Whatch_Directory> queue 
    = new LinkedBlockingQueue<classes.Watchable.Whatch_Directory>(); 
queue.put(classes.Watchable.Whatch_Directory.create_watchable("dir"));
```

but everything down from the classes.Watchable etc this is the function with the watchable class everything down him isn't showing, still only the watchable is running.

Comment: What?  This is extremely confusing.

Comment: What's a Whatch_Directory?  My guess is you are trying to use a class which is not public or is named something else like WatchDirectory or Watch_Directory.  I have no idea why you would pass a Watchable on a queue in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you're creating a `Whatch_Directory` class somewhere else, trying to make a `LinkedBlockingQueue` of such things and using a factory method `create_watchable()` to create one.

If so, it appears that a Whatch_Directory is extending the [Watchable](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Watchable.html) interface (based on your other questions).  It seems that your code should become something more like:

```
class Whatch_Directory implements Watchable {
    public static Watchable create_watchable(String s) {
        // Your definition goes here
    }
}

LinkedBlockingQueue<Whatch_Directory> queue = 
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Whatch_Directory>();
queue.put(Whatch_Directory.create_watchable("dir");
```

Some more explanation of your intent would be helpful but here are some things that I suggest you check based on my understanding:

1. Make sure that `create_watchable()` returns the correct type.  It needs to be returning something of type `Whatch_Directory` based on your code.
2. Make sure that `create_watchable()` isn't returning `null` for some reason.
3. Make sure that `create_watchable()` isn't throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks :) i will try that, that watchable class just make me crazzy..